# Compiling with Mongo C++ driver returns undefined reference to `u_strFromUTF8_66'

Tags: c, mongodb, c++11, mongo-cxx-driver, mongo-c-driver

I installed Mongo C++ Driver using following shell script,

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Building MongoDB Core Dependency"
cd /home &&
wget https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/releases/download/1.17.0/mongo-c-driver-1.17.0.tar.gz &&
tar xzf mongo-c-driver-1.17.0.tar.gz &&
cd mongo-c-driver-1.17.0 &&
mkdir cmake-build &&
cd cmake-build &&
cmake -DENABLE_AUTOMATIC_INIT_AND_CLEANUP=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .. &&
echo "Installing MongoDB Core Dependency" &&
sudo make install &&
cd /home &&
echo "Downloading MongoDB Driver" &&
git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver.git --branch releases/stable --depth 1 &&
cd mongo-cxx-driver/build &&
echo "Building and Installing MongoDB Driver" &&
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release  -DBUILD_SHARED_AND_STATIC_LIBS=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local  &&
make && sudo make install
```

I compile my app like this (w/ Static Linking),

```
g++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -ltins -DMONGOCXX_STATIC /
-DBSONCXX_STATIC -DMONGOC_STATIC / 
-DBSON_STATIC - I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 /
-I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/mongocxx/v_noabi /
-I/usr/local/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi -L/usr/local/lib -lmongocxx-static /
-lbsoncxx-static -lmongoc-static-1.0 -lz -lsasl2 -lssl -lcrypto -lrt / 
-lresolv -pthread -lbson-static-1.0 /
-lm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so /
-pthread -o app
```

However, The compile process fails with,

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libmongoc-static-1.0.a(mongoc-scram.c.o): in function `_mongoc_sasl_prep_impl':
mongoc-scram.c:(.text+0x61e): undefined reference to `u_strFromUTF8_66'
/usr/bin/ld: mongoc-scram.c:(.text+0x66a): undefined reference to `u_strFromUTF8_66'
/usr/bin/ld: mongoc-scram.c:(.text+0x685): undefined reference to `usprep_openByType_66'
/usr/bin/ld: mongoc-scram.c:(.text+0x6b0): undefined reference to `usprep_prepare_66'
/usr/bin/ld: mongoc-scram.c:(.text+0x702): undefined reference to `usprep_prepare_66'
/usr/bin/ld: mongoc-scram.c:(.text+0x720): undefined reference to `usprep_close_66'
/usr/bin/ld: mongoc-scram.c:(.text+0x739): undefined reference to `u_strToUTF8_66'
/usr/bin/ld: mongoc-scram.c:(.text+0x77a): undefined reference to `u_strToUTF8_66'
/usr/bin/ld: mongoc-scram.c:(.text+0x814): undefined reference to `usprep_close_66'
/usr/bin/ld: mongoc-scram.c:(.text+0x871): undefined reference to `usprep_close_66'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:3: all] Error 1
```

It was worked before on my other machine and not sure why it doesn't work right now.

I even reinstalled Ubuntu and that didn't work out too.

My Ubuntu version is `20.04` and G++ version is `9.3.0`

Comment: u_strFromUTF8 etc are functions from the icu library, but on my system they don't have the _66 suffix. You may need to recompile your mongo libraries and/or link against libicu<whatever>.

Comment: @ n. 'pronouns' m I followed official instructions from mongocxx docs. It worked before and I don't know why it doesn't.

Comment: A modified version of icu comes bundled with mongodb. Mangled icu names are a part of this modified library. You may need to link against the library that exports these symbols. Use `nm` tool to find the library.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this answer as a note to my future self (and other future selves):

If you don't need SASL (which in my case I don't), the easiest way around this problem (but not fixing it) is to change the mongo-c-client cmake flags to include:

```
-DENABLE_SASL=OFF
```

this solves my problem, but not actually *this* problem ...